# At what point should I store an array of objects in a db?

Tags: react-native

I'm making my first app. I have a pretty big array. I'm not sure if I should store it in a db, and access it from there instead of having it in the code base..

I understand that databases are great because it allows you update the data later. But, in my case, I won't have a pressing need to update the data later. At least not for a couple years.

Here's the array I have:

```
const example = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'eg1',
    arr1: [
      {name: '...'}
      ...
      ... * 50-100
    ],
    arr2: [
      {name: '...'}
      ...
      ... * 50-100
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'eg2',
    arr1: [
      {name: '...'}
      ...
      ... * 50-100
    ],
    arr2: [
      {name: '...'}
      ...
      ... * 50-100
    ]
  }
  ... * 10
]
```

So it isn't massive... But not small...
I have the skills to put it in a db, and grab it through an api, but this option is obviously more expensive if the array will be read a lot...

I know I could get away with either option. But, what would be the *proper* way to handle this situation?

Comment: Hardcoded data can be updated later, too. The question is really: is it going to be acceptable to need to redeploy the app to change the value?

Comment: Good point. Yes, it would be acceptable to redeploy the change later. So I think I'm leaning towards not using a db for this now. Thanks